# php session_start with include files

Tags: php, session

i learned a lot about session start from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913426/jquery-progressbar-loads-all-at-once/6913531#6913531). Now i'm wondering how session locking occurs when files are included in other files. Lets say i have:

page.php

```
include('header.php');
...some html content....
include('sub_page.php');
...more html....
```

header.php:

```
session_start();
..save session vars...
..print web page header...
```

sub_page.php

```
session_start();
...use session vars....
..print page content...
```

When i open page.php, does the session become unlocked as soon as header.php is done? or is it live for the whole page.php life, so sub_page's session is blocked? Is the `session_start` in sub_page necessary? Would it be better practice if I `session_write_close` every time i'm done with session data? (Though that would mean `session_start`ing everytime i'd like to use a session variable).

Comment: so putting all these answers together, since the include just retrieves the file and dumps it as if it were part of page.php, the second session_start isn't a valid statement, so locking isn't an issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. You should start session only one time. In your example, just need session_start() at the first line of page.php
2. session_start() will generate E_NOTICE if session was previously started. You can use @session_start() to ignore it.
3. It also generates E_NOTICE if you use session_start() after you output HTML code.

Comment: i have session_start in the header because the header is included in all my pages (page.php, page2.php, etc). i had e_notice turned off so i hadn't noticed (::rimshot::) the warning.

Comment: Agree with session_start in header because you are going to use header.php in every page. 

You should not turn off e_notice while coding, it's good for coding correction

Answer (score 10):

I would recommend creating a `session.php` file that you would include once, at the first line of each page. That way, the session is handled in ONE file, in case you need to change validation or session settings (and don't need to worry about your question).

Comment: but what happens when some sub_pages need to use session variables and some don't?

Comment: @Andrea: I'm not sure I understand. When you include a `session.php` that has the session information, it is available to all of the scripts included after it.

Comment: when you say "handle a session" do you mean "interact with the $_SESSION variable", including both setting and getting from it?

Comment: If a session is present, you can access (read and write to) `$_SESSION` from anywhere in your PHP code, as long as the `session.php` is loaded first.

Comment: i see. then currently header.php is serving that function. i could see how it would be nice to separate all that session stuff into its own file that header includes.

Answer (score 10):

Due to the answers above talking about errors if session already started, I just wanted to point out you can do:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION))
  {
    session_start();
  }
```

Then if the $_SESSION is already started (set) it wont perform the start function.

Although there's nothing better than a well structured file and folder layout with a good framework setup. Even if just a simple framework structure which separates business logic from presentation.

This way, you'd have something similar to a config folder with initialisation scripts, or at the very least have *include*  files in some folder which are included in all pages/scripts.

Then you simply have your `session_start()` in (depending on your setup) either the very first include file, or in a separate include file and then include that session file when needed in a specific area of the script.

Either way, you then don't need to call it in *any* other files, as you know it's simply not required based on your design structure.

If you do not have a file which is *always* included, then at least use the `isset()` check.

Answer (score 6):

> As of PHP 4.3.3, calling session_start() after the session was previously started will result in an error of level E_NOTICE. Also, the second session start will simply be ignored.

Comment: i had E_NOTICE turned off, so i hadn't seen this warning.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you are not accessing or creating session variables you do not need to worry about session_start(). You only really need to worry about session_start if the script you are running will create session variables, or relies on accessing session variables to function.

If file1 is not accessing or creating variables for use by other scripts then don't call it. If file2 that is included by file1 is creating or relies on variables in the session then file2 should call session_start(). File2 will be included in the session and will be able to access all session variables, but file1 will not.

If you call session_start() in file1, then file2 will be able to access all session vars as if it called session_start().

Hope this clarifies the situation a bit more.

Great tip from James re using isset. This will prevent attempting a pointless session call.

Also check your php.ini file for the session.auto_start var. If this is set to 1 then all files will be run as if they made a session_start() call. Set it to 0 in the php.ini file if you want to control it yourself.